# How can I embed a Plotly/Cufflinks iplot plots in an email report?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, cufflinks

I am working on making themed graphs and I came across the attractive [Plotly](https://pypi.org/project/plotly/) / [Cufflinks](https://plotly.com/python/cufflinks/) package.

My requirements specify that the output needs to be first stored and then embedded in output emails. Earlier I had stored [Matplotlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) graphs as PNG files and then embedded them. I can see how I can do the same with iplots here, but if I had to really take advantage of all the functionalities of my plot (the click/ zooms /hovers)... how would you suggest I go about producing it in my emails?

Some sample code, to see the kind of iplots would be:

```
>  df1.iplot(kind='line', xTitle='x title', yTitle='y title',
> theme='henanigans', asImage=True)
```

Comment: Hi, I guess you can avoid to use `iplot` with the latest plotly version. Then if you need to send as email you can save the plot as html file and check how to render it inside a mail.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Can you please elaborate on what you mean when you say "avoid using iplot with the latest version"? is there an alternative of iplot that works just as well? if yes then please elaborate / link. i have scoured the docs and im not sure what upgrade you are referring to.